# Color of HeaderButton is not changing in IOS platform in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

I am trying to change color like if the app is running in android then it shows a different color and if it's running in IOS then different color. So, I tried this.

`color={Platform.OS === "android" ? Colors.primary : "white"}`

But this isn't working in the IOS emulator.

```
headerLeft: () => (
      <HeaderButtons HeaderButtonComponent={CustomHeaderButton}>
        <Item
          title="Menu"
          iconName={Platform.OS === "android" ? "md-menu" : "ios-menu"}
          color={Platform.OS === "android" ? Colors.primary : "white"}
          onPress={() => {
            navigationData.navigation.toggleDrawer();
          }}
        />
      </HeaderButtons>
```

How can I do this in the right way?

[image]

Comment: process is correct, might be other issues

Comment: HeaderButton in ios is not visible but it's working if I click on that place.

Comment: could you please show me the whole file, mainly the import of Item

Answer (score 0):

I guess your item components return icon which you are using as a drawer button, in that case, can you check if your setting color as tint color in Item